# Other options than multiple choice and free text to solve a quiz

Tags: forms, question-answer, quiz

I currently have to develop a little online quiz: users have to guess the motif of an image which is initially hidden and revealed step by step.

It's pretty simple except the way how users should provide their answer. I did think about a free text field and multiple choice but don't consider them as proper solutions.

The problem with free text is, that it's always difficult to verify the answer considering typos and different terms for the same thing.

As well I don't think multiple choice is a valid option as it points the user to the solution.

Could you think of any other ways to solve the quiz?

Answer (score 1):

A slight variation would be if you gave them not the exact answer in the multiple choice, but only words that describe/circumscribe the real solution and they have to choose three of them / drag them on the image to describe the correct word that you are looking for (car = fast + metal + gasoline). That still gives hints, but not as concrete ones as if the solution was written down.

Or make the solution a whole sentence and they have to create that sentence using words from a word cloud and drag and arrange them to give the correct sentence (car => faster than horses and is bad for the environment).

Just some quick thoughts, not sure about the applicability in your case as the theme is not known.